# Windows 7 : Are there error logs?

Tags: windows-7, black-screen-of-death

I had a problem recently with Windows 7 on my dual Windows / Ubuntu machine. It started saying that some kind of security tag was invalid on all the files and that it was "fixing" them.

Then, next time I booted into Windows, I just get a black screen of death.

I don't have a disc drive or my original Windows disc so I can't reinstall. So I'm looking for ways I might be able to fix this. Windows isn't running but I can see the partition from Ubuntu and I was wondering whether it's possible to look at any error logs that could explain more.

If so, where would these be?

cheers

Phil

Answer (score 1):

The Windows Event Logs are stored here -

%SystemRoot%\System32\Winevt\Logs

You can copy out the existing System, Security and Application Logs to a working Windows Machine and open the logs there.

Comment: Thanks. If I don't have another Windows machine, is there a unix utility that reads them?

Comment: @interstar some quick googling found [evtx_view](http://www.tzworks.net/prototype_page.php?proto_id=4)